# Wordpress nulling PHP on one page, not on others?

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm using this script to call a link to the parent page inside one of it's children pages:

```
<?php
$this_page = get_post($id);
$parent_id = $this_page->post_parent;
if ($parent_id) {
$parent = get_page($parent_id);
echo '<a href="'.get_permalink($parent->ID).'" title="">Return to '.get_the_title($parent->ID).'</a>';}
?>
```

This sample works just fine here:
http://www.energytoolsint.com/clean-sweep/parent-test-call/

But won't parse here?
http://www.energytoolsint.com/healthcare-practitioners/

Same page template, one renders, the other doesn't.

Comment: It is working fine in both the pages. Check again?

Comment: You tagged this as wordperfect by the way... lol

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Judging by the URL, that's because energytoolsint.com/healthcare-practitioners is a parent page. Granted, you could have changed the permalink, but the URL suggests it doesn't have a parent, hence the null value.

Go to the page in dashboard. Look on the far right under the publish date.

Comment: I forgot to associate the parent page to the ladder link -.- THANK YOU KIND SIR!

Comment: You're welcome. I'd GREATLY appreciate marking this as the answer if it did the trick for you. Thanks!